# How do I make a function that will allow me to store values in a list?

Tags: function

I need to create a python function, which will recursively store fibonacci values in a list, and then return that list to me. Then, I can print that list. Here is what I have.

```
def recFib(x):
    result = []

    if x == 1:
        return result.append(1)

    if x == 2:
        return result.append(2)

    for i in range(2,x):
        result.append(recFib(i-1)+recFib(i-2))

    return result
```

I am new to Python, so alot of concepts are new to me and I seem to be unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are the values suppose to be appended to result? It seems you are appending to a different list "old", or am I missing something.

Comment: I apologize. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the @Akavall's anwer

```
def recFib(x):
    fibArray = [0, 1]
    def fib(x):
        if x < len(fibArray):
            return fibArray[x]
        temp = fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
        fibArray.append(temp)
        return temp

    return fib(x)
```

Comment: Ah nice, that's clever.

Comment: I tried that and then put for i in recFib:
      print(i), and I couldn't generate the list

Comment: I see what is going on however. I tried returning sorted(fibArray.values())

Answer (score 0):

There a few issues with you code, for example:

`return result.append(1)`

will return `None`, not `result` with `1` appended to it.

Also,

```
def recFib(x):
    result = []
```

Will set result to `[]` every time `recFib` is called, I don't think that's what you wanted.

And I am not sure that I understand your entire logic, sorry.

A possible solution is something like this:

```
def recFib(x):
    n_to_fib = {0: 0, 1: 1}
    def fib(x):
        if x in n_to_fib:
            return n_to_fib[x]
        temp = fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
        n_to_fib[x] = temp
        return temp

    return fib(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = [recFib(i) for i in range(8)]

    print result
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

And calculating new values is fast because the previous values are stored in `n_to_fib` dict and thus don't have to be recomputed.

We can also modify `recFib` to return the list directly:

```
fib(x)
return sorted(n_to_fib.values())
```

instead of:

```
return fib(x)
```

Comment: This function works well but the recFib function should return a list of n elements instead of the n'th element of that list.

Comment: @FrankBessou, I think that could be achieved with fairly slight modifications, for example returning `sorted(n_to_fib.values())`.

Comment: @coding_xeno Can you be more specific?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks alot for the help. My only question now is... do we need to define another function inside? Is there a way where I don't have to do that

Comment: @coding_xeno, Great! If you don't like nested functions, you could have `FibCalculator` class, where `self.n_to_fib` is a field, and `self.fib` is one of the methods. You could also have `n_to_fib` as a global variable, but that's not a good practice. There might be other approaches that I am not seeing..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def recFib(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [0]
    elif n == 2:
        return [0, 1] 
    else:
        a = recFib(n-1)
        return a + [a[-1] + a[-2]]
```

The key in the program is here:

```
return a + [a[-1] + b[-1]]

a       # This gets the most recently created list, since it's `recFib(n-1)`
+       # Append to the next list (but does not return `None`)
[ a[-1] # Last value of `recFib(n-1)`, which is the previous value.
+       # Add to
a[-2]]  # Second last value of `recFib(n-1)`, which is the second previous value.
```

Here are the breakpoints for `recFib(5)`:

```
n =  3
a[-1]:  1
a[-2]:  0
n =  4
a[-1]:  1
a[-2]:  1
n =  5
a[-1]:  2
a[-2]:  1
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

It doesn't require two functions. I sort of find that as cheating:

```
>>> recFib(20)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
>>> recFib(10)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
>>> recFib(19)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584]
```

Generating a list by for looping a recursive function is very inefficient. You are recalculating the whole sequence every time you use the function.

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you explain what return a + [a[-1] + b[-1]] does

Comment: @coding_xeno, see the recent edit. I also re-edited the code.